# How to open file .so?

Tags: java, android

im trying to open a file with the extension .so. In notepad++ i can see some letters and numbers, however the most character appear this way:

```
€TàÅà€˜à    ©à€˜â ©â ”à¥à Uá
 T  !    !`Vâ @ áP áïÿÿ€à å¡àö†çë åñ†çë  Xà0Éà p—âp  `wâ P ã@ á "à påâ#à à¡àÐâð½è Sá  RøO-é ` áp á9  Š  SãOoOo @„  Qão o@aà  á á  áÐ†çëP á
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: It’s a binary file that you can’t open (at least not in a meaningful way). Since it is a library file you need to get access to the source code it was built from

Comment: Question: what are you trying to achieve by opening it?

Answer (score 0):

.so files are files, that aren't meant to be read by humans. These are libraries (like .dll files on windows), that provide functions for other programs to use.
If you want a human readable representation (of the compiled code at least) try a disassembler like radare2 or ghidra.